# Minimax for conditioned UnitStep functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I made a simplified version of my problem, and I have now:

```
z=5
y=6
a + b == z
c + d  == y

Gb[x_] = UnitStep[x - 1] + 2*UnitStep[x - 2] + UnitStep[x - 3] +  2*UnitStep[x - 4]
Gg[x_]= UnitStep[x] - UnitStep[x - 3]
Gs[x_]= 5*UnitStep[x] - UnitStep[x - 1] - 2*UnitStep[x - 2] -    2*UnitStep[x - 4]

wwa[x_] = Max[0, Gs[x] - (y - c)];
wwb[x_] = Max[0, Gs[x] - wwa[x] - (y - c - d)];

wwc[x_] = Gb[x] - Max[0, Gb[x] - c];
wwd[x_] = Gb[x] - wwc[x] - Max[0, Gb[x] - wwc[x] - d];

wwe[x_] = y - wwc[x] - wwa[x];
wwf[x_] = y - wwd[x] - wwb[x];

myfunction[x_] = a*c + 1.5 b d -4 Integrate[wwd, {x, 0, a }] +
      5 Integrate[wwb, {x, 0, a }] +  3 Integrate[wwf, {x, 0, a }] - 
      6 Integrate[wwc, {x, a, a+b }] + 6 Integrate[wwa, {x, a, a+b }] + 
      4 Integrate[wwe, {x, a, a+b }]
```

`a` and `b` shall try to maximize the value of the function; 
`c` and `d` shall try to minimize the value of the function.

Can you help me out how i can achieve that with *Mathematica*?

Comment: [Defining Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)

Comment: I can't understand  "_`a` and `b` shall try to maximize the value of the function; `c` and `d` shall try to minimize the value of the function._"

Comment: Its about finding Nash-equilibrums, and it can be seen as a Zero-sum game: Lets say Player A tries to Maximize his wins (=the value of myfunction) with his parameters a and b whereas Player B tries to Minimize his losses (=the value of myfunction) with his parameters c and d. Minimax algorhythms are usually used for that. Maybe someone knows how to use the FindMinMax function found here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html on that or some other solution. Maybe even algebraic?

Comment: Could you be more clear in your question? Only [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are likely to get great answers. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Add any extra information to the question, not to the comments. Also consider taking the [tour] and choosing a meaningful username.